# WP7 - How to refer to the MainPage.xaml.vb from App.xaml.vb? (Passing data?)

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, refer

so basically I have my MainPage.xaml.vb and App.xaml.vb and in the app.xmal.vb i added :

```
 Private Sub Add_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub


Private Sub Save_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub


Private Sub EditAppBar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)


End Sub


Private Sub DeleteAppBar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

This is because I added more than 1 ApplicationBars from looking at the MSDN Sample. The problem is that how do i refer to mainpage to make the code work? e.g. the "Add" will contain "pvt.SelectedIndex = 2" and when it's clicked it's meant to navigate the the 3'rd page but i can't seem to do it in here. If i take this code and add it to the "MainPage" it will work fine. **The error i get is "'pvt' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."** How do i fix this?

Any ideas?"

Comment: I got it solved by using:
` Dim mp = TryCast(DirectCast(Application.Current, App).RootFrame.Content, MainPage)
        mp.pvt.SelectedIndex = 2 `

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by using: `Dim mp = TryCast(DirectCast(Application.Current, App).RootFrame.Content, MainPage) mp.pvt.SelectedIndex = 2`